# XAdES-BES countersignature cannot resolve reference error

Tags: bouncycastle, xades4j

I implemented verification for XAdES-BES and after testing everything works now besides counter-signatures. The same error occurs not only for files signed with xades4j but also using other software so it is not related to any mistakes in my countersignature implementation. I wonder if I should implement additional ResourceResolver? I added a countersigned file as the attachment with 'REMOVED' for some private entries [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/8ad2hpfced2kcfw/dop1.signed.countersign.applet.xades-modif.xml).

Below is the code for verification. certDataList is a list with all certificates from the document in String and getCert will return List. DummyCertificateValidationProvider returns ValidationData with a list of previously constructed x509certs.

```
    public boolean verify(final File file) {
        if (!Dictionaries.valid()) {
            return true;
        }
        certList = null;
        try {

            final DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            dbf.setNamespaceAware(true);
            final DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

            final Document doc = db.parse(file);
            doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

            final NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("ds:Signature");
            Element elem = null;
            for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {
                final Node nNode = nList.item(temp);
                if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                    elem = (Element) nNode;
                }
            }
            final NodeList nList2 = doc.getElementsByTagName("ds:X509Certificate");
            final List<String> certDataList = new ArrayList<String>();
            for (int temp = 0; temp < nList2.getLength(); temp++) {
                final Node nNode = nList2.item(temp);
                certDataList.add(nNode.getTextContent());
            }
            certList = getCert(certDataList);

            final CertificateValidationProvider certValidator = new DummyCertificateValidationProvider(certList);

            final XadesVerificationProfile p = new XadesVerificationProfile(certValidator);
            final XadesVerifier v = p.newVerifier();
            final SignatureSpecificVerificationOptions opts = new SignatureSpecificVerificationOptions();

            // for relative document paths
            final String baseUri = "file:///" + file.getParentFile().getAbsolutePath().replace("\\", "/") + "/";
            LOGGER.debug("baseUri:" + baseUri);
            opts.useBaseUri(baseUri);
            v.verify(elem, opts);
            return true;
        } catch (final IllegalArgumentException | XAdES4jException | CertificateException | IOException | ParserConfigurationException | SAXException e) {
            LOGGER.error("XML not validated!", e);
        }

        return false;
}
```

Here is the stacktrace:

```
21:31:48,203 DEBUG ResourceResolver:158 - I was asked to create a ResourceResolver and got 0 
21:31:48,203 DEBUG ResourceResolver:101 - check resolvability by class org.apache.xml.security.utils.resolver.ResourceResolver 
21:31:48,204 DEBUG ResolverFragment:137 - State I can resolve reference: "#xmldsig-5de7b1d0-be70-4dde-b746-3f4d4d6de39f-sigvalue" 
21:31:48,204 ERROR SignComponent:658 - XML not validated!

xades4j.XAdES4jXMLSigException: Error verifying the signature
    at xades4j.verification.XadesVerifierImpl.doCoreVerification(XadesVerifierImpl.java:284)
    at xades4j.verification.XadesVerifierImpl.verify(XadesVerifierImpl.java:188)
    at com.signapplet.sign.SignComponent.verify(SignComponent.java:655)
...

Caused by: org.apache.xml.security.signature.MissingResourceFailureException: The Reference for URI #xmldsig-5de7b1d0-be70-4dde-b746-3f4d4d6de39f-sigvalue has no XMLSignatureInput
Original Exception was org.apache.xml.security.signature.ReferenceNotInitializedException: Cannot resolve element with ID xmldsig-5de7b1d0-be70-4dde-b746-3f4d4d6de39f-sigvalue
Original Exception was org.apache.xml.security.utils.resolver.ResourceResolverException: Cannot resolve element with ID xmldsig-5de7b1d0-be70-4dde-b746-3f4d4d6de39f-sigvalue
    at org.apache.xml.security.signature.Manifest.verifyReferences(Manifest.java:414)
    at org.apache.xml.security.signature.SignedInfo.verify(SignedInfo.java:259)
    at org.apache.xml.security.signature.XMLSignature.checkSignatureValue(XMLSignature.java:724)
    at org.apache.xml.security.signature.XMLSignature.checkSignatureValue(XMLSignature.java:656)
    at xades4j.verification.XadesVerifierImpl.doCoreVerification(XadesVerifierImpl.java:277)
    ... 39 more
Caused by: org.apache.xml.security.signature.ReferenceNotInitializedException: Cannot resolve element with ID xmldsig-5de7b1d0-be70-4dde-b746-3f4d4d6de39f-sigvalue
```

---

**Edit:**
The same error occurs when I try to validate file provided with xades4j unit tests document.signed.bes.cs.xml.

```
Caused by: org.apache.xml.security.signature.MissingResourceFailureException: The Reference for URI #xmldsig-281967d1-74f8-482c-8222-ed58dbd1909b-sigvalue has no XMLSignatureInput
Original Exception was org.apache.xml.security.signature.ReferenceNotInitializedException: Cannot resolve element with ID xmldsig-281967d1-74f8-482c-8222-ed58dbd1909b-sigvalue
Caused by: org.apache.xml.security.signature.ReferenceNotInitializedException: Cannot resolve element with ID xmldsig-281967d1-74f8-482c-8222-ed58dbd1909b-sigvalue
```

Comment: Everything looks right with the signature. There are tests over counter signatures. The only difference I'm seeing is that on the tests the Id attribute of the root signature element is set as the XML ID of that element. But I don't think it would impact reference resolving. And ResolverFragment states it can resolve the ref...

Comment: I've just checked validation of document.signed.bes.cs.xml (in xades4j test resources) and I have the same error. It looks like I must be missing something in the code validation. I added the stacktrace from the validation of document.signed.bes.cs.xml at the end of my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with ds:Signature. In counter signatures you will have more than one ds:Signature entry. In my verification method I used the for loop:

```
    for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {
        final Node nNode = nList.item(temp);
        if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
            elem = (Element) nNode;
        }
    }
```

As you can see, there was no break when element was found so I ended up with the last ds:Signature, not the first one so all previous signatures could not be found.